# Sorting and Displaying a Linked List

Tags: c, data-structures

I am writing a library management program where the user can add books to a database which just means that the program will take the user's input and store it into a text document.  Then, when the program starts up it will read through the text document where all the books are stored and build a linked list where each book would be a node.  So, I have been able to get to a point where I can read the text file and store the values into nodes.  However, when I try testing the bookList function to view the entire book list by title my program crashes.  Here is the code:

```
void loadingMenu(){

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    int lines = 0;
    char line[254];

    char *ti = malloc(MAX_STR_LEN);
    char *au = malloc(MAX_STR_LEN);
    char *ca = malloc(MAX_STR_LEN);
    char *id = malloc(MAX_STR_LEN);
    char *ti_chopped;
    char *au_chopped;
    char *ca_chopped;
    char *id_chopped;

    int id_num;

    struct node *tempNode;
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){

        if(line == 'EOF'){
            break;
        }
        if(lines == 7){
           lines = 0;
        }
        if(lines == 0){
            line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0; // remove '\n' from string
            strcpy(ti, line);
        }
        else if(lines == 1){
            line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;
            strcpy(au, line);
        }
        else if(lines == 3){
            line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;
            strcpy(ca, line);
        }
        else if(lines == 6){
            line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;
            strcpy(id, line);
        }
        lines++;

        if(lines == 6){
            // removing the identifiers from each string
            ti_chopped = ti + 6;
            au_chopped = au + 7;
            ca_chopped = ca + 9;
            id_chopped = id + 3;

            id_num = atoi(id_chopped);

            // ------create book node------------
            tempNode = malloc(sizeof *tempNode);
            // ----------------------------------
            tempNode->next = NULL;
            tempNode->titleptr = malloc(strlen(ti_chopped) + 1);
            strcpy(tempNode->titleptr, ti_chopped);

            tempNode->authorptr = malloc(strlen(au_chopped) + 1);
            strcpy(tempNode->authorptr, au_chopped);

            tempNode->categoryptr = malloc(strlen(ca_chopped) + 1);
            strcpy(tempNode->categoryptr, ca_chopped);

            tempNode->id = id_num;

            //printf("%d", tempNode->id);
            head = addNode(head, tempNode);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

}


int compareNode(struct node *n1, struct node *n2){

    int compareValue = strcmp(n1->titleptr, n2->titleptr);

    if(compareValue == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(compareValue < 0){
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}

struct node *addNode(struct node *list, struct node *node1){

    struct node* tmp = list;

    if(list == NULL){
        return node1;
    }
    if(compareNode(node1,list) == -1){
        node1->next = list;
        list = node1;
        return list;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node* prev = list;
        while(tmp != NULL && compareNode(node1, tmp) >= 0){
            prev = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        prev->next = node1;
        node1->next = tmp;
        return list;
    }

}

void bookList(){

    system("cls");
    struct node *tmp;
    tmp = head;

    printf("List of all Books: ");

    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", tmp->titleptr);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    printf("\n\nEnd of list.");
}
```

First off I would like to apologize for the bad code, also I trimmed away some of the fat of the program and just left the functions involved behind.

So, please if you could help me out on this or at least point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.  Also, if you have any coding tips or comments go ahead and tell me, I am always hungry to learn!

EDIT: The code now runs and the list will print, however, the strings will not be in alphabetical order.  Currently trying to figure that out.

Comment: Could you cut this down to just the important parts?

Comment: Also when you say "the function" can you tell us *which* function? Where is the error?

Comment: If `if(line == 'EOF')` compiles without a warning, then you do not have any warnings enabled.  It is completely pointless to be trying to code in C without the maximum number of warnings enabled.  Please enable all warnings (should be something like a `/Wall` option to the compiler) before doing anything else.

Comment: You have a debugger and know how to use it, yes?

Comment: Also, as @MikeNakis hints at, you should read up on how to compare NULL-terminated char arrays.

Comment: @MartinJames yes, but you see, if he does not enable all warnings first, it will still be pointless to try programming in C, even if he becomes an *expert* in comparing NULL-terminated char arrays.

Comment: I just cut it down as much as I think is good and sorry about that I was trying to run the bookList function. @NickZ

Comment: Just did that and I am getting that warning now along with many others, thanks for the head up @MikeNakis

Comment: I wish I could say I know how to use it properly, but I can't.  I will do some reading now on how to use it correctly, thanks for the comment @MartinJames

Comment: Try to see if you can print the value of the head

Comment: I can print the head now but the strings got mixed up into a random order somehow, so that means my addNode or compareNode function is wrong.    @NickZ The problem with the bookList function was I had system('cls') when it needed to be system("cls").

Comment: this looks like a homework question, I would advise you to do this yourself!

Answer (score 1):

In the first addNode() function, you need to set the previous pointer. That should fix the problem.

```
if(compareNode(node1,list) == -1)
{
        node1->next = list;
        list->prev = node1;
        list = node1;
        return list;
}
```